# CSS resize element on click

Tags: css, onclick, resize, transition

Please have a look at the page to start with: http://codepen.io/Mickael/pen/ztqnp?editors=110

What I'm trying to do is when one clicks on the little icon in the upper right hand corner, the parent container resizes it by increasing its width to 100% (currently set to a `px` value as there is another element on the right of it (the task list)).

I would like to do the following:

1. on click of the icon, use transition to expand the width to 100%
2. once expanded, I want the container to be covering the task list completely (I can work that one out with z-index and position)
3. once the box is expanded to 100%, I would like the arrow in the icon at the top to change to the left pointing arrows (that's the second svg that's commented out in the html)

Any help is greatly appreciated... Ive googled transition, resizing, dynamic width and all sorts but can't find anything that would point me in the right direction of what Im trying to do here.

Thanks in advance

```
div#middle-container {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 355px);            <--------- resize this to 100%
    max-height: calc(100% - 105px);
    margin-left: 65px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0 !important;
    top: 55px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), /*bottom internal shadow*/
    inset 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1); /*top internal highlight*/ 
    background-color: #777;
}
```

Comment: I not sure that the CSS can trap event. You might want to consider using javascript to do that.

Comment: Yep,, click events are JS events except for...ahem...'hacky' checkbox alternatives.

Comment: That's a shame.. I don't know JavaScript! lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy by defining a couple of new classes.

One for the container...here I've used `full`

```
div#middle-container.full {
  width:70%; /* demo only, should be 100% in your case */
}
```

..and one for the toggle

```
#desktop-nav-toggle.switch {
  transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

Then a little Jquery to toggle the classes on and off

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#desktop-nav-toggle').click(function() {
   $(this).parent().toggleClass('full');
   $(this).toggleClass('switch');
  });
});
```

I threw in a couple of transitions in the [**Codepen.io Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/zLHbx)

Comment: Thank you Paulie... it does exactly what I want!!! I'll have to change a couple of things to make it work with my site but that's spot on what I wanted it to do :) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you could also do something like this: 
Remember to load the Jquery library into your project otherwise it wont work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#desktop-nav-toggle').on( "click", function() {
    $('#middle-container').toggleClass('maxWidth')
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#desktop-nav-toggle').on( "click", function() {
    $('#middle-container').css("width","100%")
  });
});
```

Let learn Jquery
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css_classes.asp